$2$-stage Unordered Sampling with Replacement: Expected Number of most Draws?
Let $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$ be finite sets and for $i=1,\dots,N$ put $X_i\sim\mathcal U (\mathcal X)$ and $Y_i\sim\mathcal U(\mathcal Y)$ (all of them independent and uniformly distributed). Put $\vec{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_N)$ and $\vec{Y}=(Y_1,\dots,Y_N)$ and for all $(x,y)\in\mathcal X\times \mathcal Y$ define the random variable
\begin{equation}
N(x,y):=\lvert \{ i=1,\dots,N \mid (X_i,Y_i)=(x,y)\}\rvert.
\end{equation}
One easily computes for all $x,y$ and $i=1,\dots,N$ that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P(N(x,y) = i)= \binom{N}{i}p^i(1-p)^i
\end{equation}
with $p=\frac{1}{\lvert \mathcal X\times\mathcal Y\rvert}$. Now fix $x\in\mathcal X$. My goal is to compute
\begin{equation}
\mathbb E_{(\vec{X},\vec{Y})}\left[ \max_{y\in\mathcal Y} N(x,y) \right]
\end{equation}
(this value should be independent of $x$). How would one go about this?
My Attempt: I tried to compute the distribution of this maximum via the counter event:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P( \max_{y\in\mathcal Y} N(x,y)\leq j) = \mathbb P(\forall y\in\mathcal Y: N(x,y)\leq j) = 1 - \mathbb P(\exists  y\in\mathcal Y: N(x,y)\geq j+1).
\end{equation}
However I don"t see how this gets me any further.

You have used $N$ to denote two different things.

The case of $|\mathcal X|=1$ is discussed here and there doesn't seem to be a closed form answer.
